# Angular NgTable pagination doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

i'm trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong, and can't find examples
with the new version of NgTable

i can get the reload and the array from NgTable, but my pagination doesn't work

since somethings were deprecated can't find a way to do with the new changes.

this is with `ng-table v 0.8.3`

```
$scope.listaDetalleFactura = function () {
                var idFacturaDetalle = $routeParams.idFactura;
                $scope.detalleFacturas = "";
                $promesa = facturaService.getDetalleFacturaList(idFacturaDetalle);
                $promesa.then(function (datos) {
                    $scope.detalleFacturas = datos.data;
                    var data = datos.data;
                    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                        page: 1,
                        count: 5
                    }, {
                        total: data.length,
                        getData: function (params) {
                            data = $scope.detalleFacturas;
                            params.total(data.length);
                            if (params.total() <= ((params.page() - 1) * params.count())) {
                                params.page(1);
                            }
                            return data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                        }});
                });
            };
```

my table:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" style="margin-top: 10px;" 
                                       class="table-condensed table-bordered table-striped"                                   
                                       data-ng-init="listaDetalleFactura()"
                                       >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width: 40px; text-align: center;">Id</th>
                                            <th style="width: 300px;">Descripcion</th>
                                            <th style="width: 30px; text-align: center;">Cantidad</th>
                                            <th style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">Precio por Unidad</th>
                                            <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">Descuento</th>
                                            <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">Total</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="detalleFactura in detalleFacturas">
                                            <td style="text-align: center;">{{detalleFactura.idDetalleFactura}}</td>
                                            <td>{{detalleFactura.producto.descripcion}}</td>
                                            <td style="width: 30px; text-align: center;">{{detalleFactura.cantidadDetalle}}</td>
                                            <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">{{detalleFactura.producto.precioVenta}}</td>
                                            <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">{{detalleFactura.descuentoDetalle}}</td>
                                            <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">{{detalleFactura.totalDetalle}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: You can use dir pagination. Besides being simpler than ngTable, can paginate almost everything, not only tables. https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Comment: thank you so much, it will helpful to another things!!

Comment: Glad to help. I also used ngTable before I discovered the awesome dirPagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i'm feeling sooo dumb, sorry for waste ur time... hope this will be helpul to someone some day....

my error was in the `ng-repeat` instead of `detalleFacturas` i should use `$data`

```
<tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="detalleFactura in $data">
                                        <td style="text-align: center;">{{detalleFactura.idDetalleFactura}}</td>
                                        <td>{{detalleFactura.producto.descripcion}}</td>
                                        <td style="width: 30px; text-align: center;">{{detalleFactura.cantidadDetalle}}</td>
                                        <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">${{detalleFactura.producto.precioVenta}}</td>
                                        <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">{{detalleFactura.descuentoDetalle}}</td>
                                        <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">${{detalleFactura.totalDetalle}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
```

Comment: Do you have a Plunker for that .. can you create a working plunker with some sample data with pagination .. your Help will be rewarded full :-) if you can ...